# PIL image contact sheet syntax error in if statement

Tags: if-statement, python-imaging-library

Trying to add images to a contact sheet but getting a syntax error in the following line, 7 from the bottom (in italics with stars around it), please can someone help?

```
# facecrops is a list of the PIL image objects
print(face_crops)
# create contact sheet to paste images to
contact_sheet=Image.new('RGB', (500,300))
# add each resized cropped image to the contact sheet
# use one variable for the X dimension, and one for the Y dimension.
x=0
y=0
for pic in face_crops:
    # first resize the cropped face
    smallpic = size_to_fit(pic)
    # Lets paste the current image into the contact sheet
    contact_sheet.paste(smallpic, (x, y, smallpic.size[0], smallpic.size[1] )
    # update our position. If it is going to be greater than the width of the image, then set it to 0
    # and update Y as well to point to the next "line" of the contact sheet.
    if (x + smallpic.width) >= contact_sheet.width:
        x=0
        y=y+smallpic.height
    else:
        x=x+smallpic.width
display(contact_sheet)
```

not sure what to try

Comment: it is the following line: if (x + smallpic.width) >= contact_sheet.width:

Comment: Please click [edit] and put all the details of the error and where it occurs in your question rather than in the comments. Thank you.